# How to define Locale scope?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, scoping

I want to create different Bean instances for different Locales in my program, but I don't know too much about the scoping mechanism in Spring CDI. How does scope-proxy determine which proxy-target to forward, if there are two request-scoped instances of the same bean is simulaneously in used?

I can get the Locale preference from an http request, and then I want to get the correct bean in that specific locale. Rather then using "prototype" scope, Locale-scope will create only a few instances for locales in used only. Personally, I want something like this in my own way:

```
@Component
@Scope("locale")
class MyService {

    @Inject
    @Named("scope-invariant")
    public MyService(Locale locale) {
        ResourceBundle nls = getResourceBundle(..., locale);
        // ...
    }

}

@Controller
class MyController {

    void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        UserPreference userPreference = getUserPreference(req, res.getSession(), ...);
        Locale userLocale = userPreference.getUserLocale();

        applicationContext.doInScope(
            new ScopeBinding("locale", userLocale), 
            new ScopedCallback() {

                @Inject
                MyService service;

                void execute() {
                    // ...
                }

            });
    }

}
```

Well, it's obviously not work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

See [related wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/utils-apl-derived/wiki/LocaleBeanScope) for a LocaleBeanScope implementation